# React Native custom toggle button component

Tags: react-native, radio-button, components, toggle, custom-controls

I have been working on a custom component that acts similar to a radio button, but now have a few questions on how I can extend it.

I want to be able set TouchableOpacity style via a stylesheet which is currently done inline due to the dynamic nature of it.

I also want to be able to pass a second variable/string in price through.

Further to the above if I can send through 2 variables these will be coming via firebase/props so how would I expose them.

**Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import styles from './Styles/OptionStyle'

export default class Option extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeOption: this.props.options[0],
    };
  }
  updateActiveOption = (activeOption) => {
    this.setState({
      activeOption,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.props.options.map((option, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity key={index} style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.onChange(option);
              this.updateActiveOption(option);
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                width: 100,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: this.state.activeOption === option ? '#4caf50' : 'rgb(117, 117, 118)',
                borderRadius: 6,
                height: 100,
                padding: 10,
                color: this.state.activeOption === option ? '#4caf50' : 'rgb(117, 117, 118)'
              }}
            >
              {option}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Calling the component

```
<Option
            options={['Small','Medium','Large']}
            onChange={(option) => {
              console.log(option);
            }}
          />
```

This is where I would like to be able to pass 2 variables per option ie Small and $3.95 or Medium and $4.95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass array of objects via props and then use them in your component. Something like this:

```
<Option
        options={[{label: 'Small', price: '$3.95'},{label: 'Medium', price: '$4.95'}]}
        onChange={(option) => {
          console.log(option);
        }}
      />
```

And then in your Component simply iterate over it for example with map:

```
{this.props.options.map((option, index) => (
 <TouchableOpacity><Text>{option.label} - {option.value}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
))}
```

Comment: I was more trying to work out how I can use this.props.data.options to set options={ part if this is possible. Thanks

Comment: I still don't know if I udnerstand what is the problem, but it is possible that you just want to pass down props. This can be done in several ways, for example: 

    <Component {...this.props.data} />

Comment: what I mean is can I do <Option options={this.props.data.options}/> which will have the label and price in it?